# creating x64 program in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I have a program in VS2010 on vista x64 and i have it running for an x86 target machine and it built. I am trying to change it to x64 target machine.

I have changed the project config to x64 target machine and i also changed the build configurations to x64.

However when i build it, it cannot find any of the header files that are in the code files. All the #include  files can't be found. I've tried moving the header files around so it could see them. I put them in the x64 project folder etc. the x86 version was able to build using the SDK installed in Program Files(x86) so i tried moving it to the Program Files but i'm getting

fatal error C1083: cannot open include file: 'header.h': no such file or directory

What do i need to do to make the project see them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are building a C++ project.  If so, you need to check the properties for the project that is having problems (right-click on the project and select Properties).  Notice that you can select the platform, and the properties can be different per platform.  Compare the directories from the x86 (or Win32) architecture to the x64 architecture and see what, if anything, is different.

Comment: Would it be easier to create an x64 program or a WoW64 program?

Comment: @user737018 WoW64 is certainly easier, but occasionally (for reasons I don't completely understand) you can't.  If you wrote everything yourself, you can probably do so.  I've had problems when linking to certain third-party DLLs, though.